# MySQL php utf-8 format issues

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

So here we go,i have this problem first here is my code

```
$servername = DB_HOSTNAME;
$username = DB_USERNAME;
$password = DB_PASSWORD;
$dbname = DB_DATABASE;
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
/*UTF-8 format*/
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

$clean0 = "SET NAMES utf8;";
$clean1 = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$DeleteWord1', '$empty') WHERE name LIKE '%$FindWord1%';";

if ($conn->query($clean0) === TRUE) {
    echo "<h1>Product unwanted names deleted successfully</h1>";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

if ($conn->query($clean1) === TRUE) {
    echo "<h1>Product unwanted names deleted successfully</h1>";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

The code works fine by itself if i don't use Bulgarian letters.
but when i use bulgarian letters the code does not want to find $DeleteWord1

when i `varp_dump($clean1)`

I get

```
    string 'UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name,
 'Р§РђРЎРћР’РќРРљ', ' ') WHERE name LIKE '%SHEEN%';' (length=103)
```

As you guys can see it's not converted in a UTF-8 aparently for some reason and that's why it does not work with bulgarian letters,

BUT! it works with Bulgarian letters in a Local-Host but not on a Live hosting account

Both databases have collation of utf-8_general_ci (localhost & livehost one)

Any ideas how can i fix this?

```
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

$clean0 = "SET NAMES utf8;";
```

Both of those were supposed to do that i tried by themselves **e.g** only `charset` and only set names,same issue

And 1 more thing,how can i see if it really passes the values like Р§РђРЎРћР’РќР? since when i set the cleaner.php file to `<meta charser="utf-8">` it comes out normally.Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of `UTF-8` try using `ISO-8859-5`. For me `UTF-8` works well in html, but in php I need to use an ISO

Comment: Check the venerable duplicate and see to it that you're using UTF-8 **all the way through**.

Comment: @Comum PHP can handle UTF-8 just fine.

Comment: The other post helped me the issue was in UTF-8 i set it up to utf8mb4 and everything worked fine